# Teradata - Get the 2nd most current date, from a table, and reference it

Tags: teradata

Lets say we have a table with entries and run dates.  It might get updated on weekends or holidays, or it might just run M-F.  And this check could run before all loads are done for the day.  For this reason, I want to find the entry before the max date.

```html
Run_Date    Entry
2020-03-09  z
2020-03-06  x
2020-03-05  y
```

In this instance, I want to return 3/6/20.  I would use this in a CTE or subquery.

This code returns the top two dates, and we see the 2nd date 3/6, but how do I single it out?

```
SELECT TOP 2
RUN_DATE
FROM DATABSE1.TABLEA
GROUP BY RUN_DATE
ORDER BY RUN_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  RUN_DATE
FROM DATABSE1.TABLEA
QALIFY 
  ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (ORDER BY RUN_DATE DESC) = 2 -- 2nd highest date
```

This assumes RUN_DATE is unique, otherwise switch to DENSE_RANK plus DISTINCT

Comment: Thanks!  The dates were not unique, so I went with your 2nd option:

    SELECT DISTINCT(RUN_DATE)
    FROM DATABSE1.TABLEA
    QUALIFY 
      Dense_Rank() 
      Over (ORDER BY RUN_DATE DESC) = 2